# How to work out values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to do the question below but I do not understand how to work it out. Please if you can break it down to me, it would be appreciated. Thanks guys!

What is the value of "s" after each line is executed?

```
var str="Hello World"
s = str.indexOf("o");
s = str.indexOf("w");
s = str.indexOf("r");
s = str.lastIndexOf("l");
```

Comment: 4 , -1 , 8 and 9 will be the result.

Comment: Some reading material: [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [String.prototype.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: Your class doesn't have an ebook they told you to buy?

Comment: Why not just execute it and log the results? Has StackOverflow become an alternative JavaScript Runtime?

Comment: An obvious homework assignment with no effort to crack open a book or the use of Google

Answer (score 0):

The *string is treated as if it were an array of characters* and the indexOf looks for the first occurrence of the provided string. If it does not find it then it returns -1 to indicate not found.

```
var str="Hello World"
s = str.indexOf("o");
console.log(s); //4th position - indexes are begin at zero - so its fifth in the array.
s = str.indexOf("w");
console.log(s); //-1 - not found
s = str.indexOf("r");
console.log(s); //8
s = str.lastIndexOf("l");
console.log(s); //9
```

Comment: There's no conversion to array. There are `.indexOf()` and `.lastIndexOf()` on the String prototype. It's probably fair to say something like *the string is treated as if it were an array of characters ...*.

Comment: @Pointy Remember that `String.indexOf()` is present since (around when) Javascript was created, while `Array.indexOf()` was added a few (2-3) years ago.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes, I remember :)